# how to get timestamp from header

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS fans..

I am new in ROS.. I try to make a simple node that subscribes timestamp from a messages with a header and a timestamp here..

> ```
> http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html
> ```

As Describe in this tutorial

> ```
> http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29,
> ```

I make a simple coding like this..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import rospy 
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_name() + ": I heard %s" % data.header)

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('get_timestamp', JointState, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

But I get this error..

> ```
>  rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_name() + ": I heard %s" % data.header)
>       TypeError: float argument required, not Header
> ```

why float argument required ? How to solve that problem..

Actually I am confuse with the Sensor_msgs/JointState, because the type of the header is std_msgs/header.

how to subscribe it from sensor_msgs/JointState to get timestamp ?

I hope someone can help me.. :) Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60819/how-to-get-timestamp-from-header/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you are seeing has to do with the string formatting. Oddly, I see that error if I use `%f`, but not `%s` (`%s` should try to convert the argument to a `str`). If you want just the timestamp, use `data.header.stamp`

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-04-16**:
Thanks @Dan Lazewatsky
it works ^_^